# Add SNS as a event listener to the s3 without adding additional policy

Tags: aws-cdk

I have an SNS which will listen to multiple S3 buckets. SNS is having the access policy like below.

```json
{
      "Sid": "0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:dummy-topic-name",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      }
    }
```

This permission will allow all s3 buckets to send notification to the SQS. Currently, I'm adding SNS to S3 buckets event settings like below.

```js
bucketList.forEach(bucket => bucket.addEventNotification(EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new SnsDestination(snsTopic)));
```

This one works well, but it adds additional policy to the SNS access policy, like below.

```json
{
      "Sid": "2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:dummy-topic-name",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::dummy-s3-bucket"
        }
      }
    }
```

I have lots of buckets (in the 100's) sending notifications to the same SNS. Now, 100 policies like above will hit the SNS access policy size limit.

Is there a way to add SNS to the S3 event notification without updating the SNS access policy using CDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Replace the CDK-generated `AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy` with a manually defined one.

As you say, `bucket.addEventNotification` adds a bucket-specific statement to the topic's resource policy resource (`AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy`).  Use [escape hatch syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource) to delete the generated `AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy`. Add a new one by hand:

Identify the generated CfnTopicPolicy's CDK construct id.

```js
const childIds = topic.node.children.map((c) => c.node.id);
console.log(childIds); // -> [ 'Resource', 'Policy' ]
```

Looks like the construct id is "Policy".  Remove it.

```js
const success = topic.node.tryRemoveChild('Policy');
if (!success) throw new Error('Could not remove the Topic Policy!');
```

Add the desired policy manually.

```js
new sns.TopicPolicy(this, 'TopicPolicy', {
    topics: [topic],
    policyDocument: new iam.PolicyDocument({
    statements: [
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ['sns:Publish'],
        principals: [new iam.ServicePrincipal('s3.amazonaws.com')],
        conditions: { StringEquals: { 'AWS:SourceAccount': this.account } },
        resources: [topic.topicArn],
        }),
    ],
    }),
});
```